# npm install causes Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: node.js, npm, aws-sdk

I run npm i and got this message:

```
npm i
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/minta-dan/.npm/_logs/2021-02-01T12_07_22_367Z-debug.log
```

in the log I can tell that everything installed but:

```
619 timing idealTree Completed in 47459ms
4620 timing command:install Completed in 47463ms
4621 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
4621 verbose stack     at Arborist.[canPlaceDep] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1387:62)
4621 verbose stack     at Arborist.[placeDep] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1061:36)
4621 verbose stack     at Arborist.[placeDep] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1212:41)
4621 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:766:46
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue. After npm install -g npm@latest I could no longer reproduce. Perhaps you want to give it a try.

taken from:
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/11238

Comment: this did not solve the problem. the problem occurred in version 7.x and now the latest version of npm is 7.x. instead I installed npm@6

Answer (score 1):

Needless to say I ran into the same problem and the log file did not really give me any clue of what was wrong.  I was using `node V16.10.6` when I first ran into this issue.  I tried upgrading to `node V18.15.0`, but it failed to upgrade because my GLIBC was an old version (I am running **CentOS 7**).  I did not want to start messing with other installations so I decided to downgrade to `node V14.21.3` and this version gave me a better idea of what was wrong.  Somehow my package-lock.json file was corrupted.  I deleted the file and was able to run `npm i` successfully.  Hope this help someone...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when trying to run `npm install` on a project with a yarn.lock file. If that's your situation, I suggest you run `yarn install` instead or [do the conversion](https://github.com/imsnif/synp)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem not running *npm i* but while installing the *ycm-core/YouCompleteMe* plugin for **vim**. Running *npm install -g npm@latest* didn't solve the issue. But it stopped occurring only when I changed the '**global**' default to false in file *~/.nmprc*:

```
global=false
```

Before that, I updated all global packages without success:

```
npm -g outdated
npm -g update
```

I learned that maybe it is a good idea to use global only when required with '-g' flag.

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same error, but for me, the solution was the rollback of npm to the 7.0.0 version (from the latest - 7.17.0).